# Which is the better way to implement authentication using login/password AND other social networks?

Tags: api, oauth, restful-authentication

I'm gonna try to explain my problem :

I'd like to allow users to connect to my api via their own accounts (login/password) or via a social network (Facebook at first).

Then, I would allow any application to use my api, with the user authenticated.

My first thought when to auth the user via his/her login/password and return a token used as the session for the next requests.

But OAuth would seems to be the better implementations, except I don't know how to do this :

- One of my applications will have to connect via login/password, like twitter web (I have to implement an login/password auth somewhere if I wan't my user to login :p)
- Will I also have to register my applications to the oauth system (did twitter added their web app to their oauth ?)
- How to merge the auth via others social networks. Concretely, the user will have to OAuth to my api that will auth to the social network.

I'm a bit lost on how to do this, if someone could help me, I would really appreciate !

Thanks

**Update 1**:
Flickr and Lastfm seems to not use OAuth but an alternative auth system that looks like this :

- The user is redirected to Flickr/Lastfm
- The user auth himself and accept to use the application
- Flickr/Lastfm return to the Callback url with a temporary frob (for flickr) or token (for lastfm)
- The app must call the provider with the temporary frob/token (among with the api_key and the api_sig, as always) and get in return the session token to use for the next calls.

**Update 2**:
In fact, StackApps is the concrete case of my problem : you can login through their login/password system OR openId, and you can use their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is only needed to make others use your API on other services, i.e. authorize services to use your API without users of the intermediary service explicitly having to log in into your service by giving user's login credentials to a third party.

What I think you need is [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), the cross-application *authentication* mechanism. You just need to implement an OpenID client, accepting third-party OpenIDs to authenticate users, to subsequently identify them, when they use your service's API. This would have to be supplemented with a normal 'local' user authentication mechanism (i.e. login/password entry page)

You will need OAuth to provide an ability to use your API on other sites, though.

Comment: Yeah you right ! I mixed OpenId aka Authentication and OAuth aka Authorization !
I have to use OpenId to authenticate user in my apps, using login/pass or third-party AND OAuth for allowing authenticated users to use my API !

Thank you ! :)

Comment: But, just a question : since my web app will consume my api (two different systems so), my web app will have to use OAuth to consume it ? like any others apps ?

Comment: Well, let's say you have two apps: one is Alpha with an API, another is Beta, which needs to use Alpha. If Alpha requires user authentication, then yes, you need Beta to use OAuth and Alpha to provide OAuth support to make it work.

Comment: Note that OAuth is designed for applications which don't fully trust each other. If both Alice and Bob are your applications, you can entrust Bob to handle Alice's user authorization and avoid any complications with OAuth.

Comment: Ok, but how could you make Alice(API) and Bob(my website) to fully trust each others without using OAuth ? Bob will still have to use Alice. I cannot only rely on the domain source (http_referer) since it can be spoofed.

Comment: No, what I meant was that you could make Bob log in to Alice just like a person would normally do, that is, make Bob impersonate the user, when authenticating to Alice via the same authentication mechanism, that the user would use. But yes, there are numerous issues with that, one being the fact, that you would have to somehow convince user that Bob service and Alice both belong to you, so it's OK for user to share his Alice password with the Bob web-service.

Comment: Now, OAuth may be the best answer still. Think of it being standard and that it thus can be expanded to other, 3rd party, services in addition to your own Alice. Also to clarify one thing in your original question: OAuth doesn't need anything to be centrally registered. It's a protocol to be executed between two parties: a client (in your case Bob -- your mashup or whatever it is) and a server (Alice, the original service). User may be required to expressly authorize Bob's requests on Alice, but that's a matter of Alice's policy.

Comment: Ok so OpenId + OAuth ! That's what its gonna be, also for Bob! I can also allow automatically the rights for Bob if it is registered as trusted service for my OAuth API in order to avoid the user to accept the use of Bob for Alice (since their are both my services). Thank you for your time! I appreciate.